# NextJS TypeScript How to define Enum for strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

In my `nextjs`-app I have a component, which has a prop of the type `string`. Now I want to define an `enum`, so I tried to do this:

```
enum Label {
 dermatology = 'Dermatologi',
 psychology = 'Psykologi',
 rheumatology = 'Reumatologi',
 physiology = 'Fysiologi',
```

}

```
interface ISpecialist {
  label?: Label
}

export default function Specialist({ specialist }: { specialist: ISpecialist }) {
   return (
      <div>
        <span>{specialist.label === Label}
      </div>
   )
}
```

but this doesn't work - can someone help me out?

the prop label is as mentioned before of the type string and the values are for example `'psychology'` or `'dermatology'`

Comment: what is that you expecting in here  `{specialist.label === Label}`

Comment: If for example the value from `specialist.label` is `'dermatology'` the output would be `Dermatologi` ... but thats apparently not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the corresponding value of the enum, access it like the enum key.

```
    <span>{Label[specialist.label] }
```

Comment: Perfect! This was what i was looking for! Thanks alot! - So obvious though... :-)